# Move UI element using constraints via code

Tags: swift, animation, autolayout, constraints

I am trying to make a simple animation using constraints.
When the button is pressed, the following occurs:

[image: First step]

[image: Second step]

I created two variables for height and boolean

```swift
    var isCollectionOpen = false
    var collectionHeightConstraint = NSLayoutConstraint()
```

Set limits for the entire user interface through code and in the same place brought the height of the collection to a variable

```swift
// ...
        btcView.collectionView.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: collectionHeightConstraint.constant),
// ...
```

And I'm trying to change the constraints on pressing the button. But nothing happens. What is my problem?

```swift
    func example() {
        collectionHeightConstraint.constant = isCollectionOpen ? (view.frame.width / 4) : 0
        isCollectionOpen = !isCollectionOpen
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is simple enough. It seems you are trying to make a constraint equal to another constraint and then just changing the other constant.

This

```
btcView.collectionView.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: collectionHeightConstraint.constant)
```

just reads the current value of `collectionHeightConstraint`. It doesn't make the constraint magically keep the same value as `collectionHeightConstraint`.

Instead:

```
var collectionHeightConstraint: NSLayoutConstraint?
```

and store reference to the created constraint:

```
collectionHeightConstraint = btcView.collectionView.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 0)
```

Then simply change it:

```
collectionHeightConstraint.constant = isCollectionOpen ? (view.frame.width / 4) : 0
```

However, this is not the best solution. I would personally create two constraints with different priorities:

```
let hiddenConstraint = btcView.collectionView.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 0)
hiddenConstraint.priority = UILayoutPriority.required - 1
self.visibleConstraint = btcView.collectionView.heightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.widthAnchor, multiplier: 1 / 4)
```

And then just toggle `visibleConstraint.isActive = false` to hide the view and `visibleConstraint.isActive = true` to hide the view.

Answer (score 1):

With the help of the answer [@Sulthan](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67952980/15692162)

I did the following:

1. Created two variables

```swift
    var isCollectionOpen = false
    var visibleConstraint: NSLayoutConstraint?
```

2. In the constraint store

```swift
    let hiddenConstraint = btcView.collectionView.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 0)
    hiddenConstraint.priority = UILayoutPriority.required - 1
    visibleConstraint = btcView.collectionView.heightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.widthAnchor, multiplier: 1 / 4)

// ...
    btcView.collectionView.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: hiddenConstraint.constant),
// ...
```

3. Where I get data into a collection

```swift
    if !isCollectionOpen {
        visibleConstraint?.isActive = true
        isCollectionOpen = true
    } else {
        visibleConstraint?.isActive = false
        isCollectionOpen = false
        return // Don't download data again
    }
```